Can the notation in the attached image be the correct notation of the tuple?
I am mathematically proving a fact related to my mathematical model in operations research and supply chain. In this regard, I wonder whether the following is the correct mathematical notation for the tuples containing a set of variables (represented by "S" with indices).

Your proposed notation is not obvious to me. If $A$ is $(1,2,3)$ and $J$ is $(5,6)$, are you looking for $\left(S_{15t}, S_{16t}, S_{25t}, S_{26t}, S_{35t}, S_{36t}\right)$ or $\left(S_{15t}, S_{25t}, S_{35t}, S_{16t}, S_{26t}, S_{36t}\right)$? Either way, I doubt there is a standard way to represent nested orders like this and it would probably be clearer to give an example with "$\ldots$".

I apologize for being erroneous here. I mean tuple instead of ordered pair.

Is $(S_{ijt}, \forall i\in A,j\in J)$ one tuple or several tuples? Three subscripts imply that $S_{ijt}$ belongs to a three-dimensional array, or is it just two subscripts and the $t$ is something else? Even a two-dimensional array is now what I'd call a "tuple". In my experience good notation comes from a clear idea about what you want it to mean, and unclear ideas yield bad notation. (Unfortunately, good ideas don't guarantee good notation.)

By the way, the preferred way to show notation here is with markup rather than pictures. The markup for your notation is $(S_{ijt}, \forall i\in A,j\in J)$.

There's no such thing as objectively correct notation - the "correct" notation is anything that you adequately define when you introduce it, and that your readers can understand.
However, I don't quite understand what you're trying to write here. My best guess is this:
It seems like you have a variable $S$, which can be separately indexed by $i$, $j$, and $t$. Your index sets for $i$ and $j$ are $A$ and $J$ respectively. You don't mention an index set for $t$, which makes me think that $t$ might be a time parameter?
I'm also not sure where the ordered pair comes into this. Are you trying to make a long ordered tuple of, for instance, $(S_{1,1,t},S_{1,2,t},\ldots)$? (Would something like a matrix be better? Do you need them to be in a single 'object' at all, or do you just need the $S$-values to be 'indexed' by $A$ and $J$?)
If my understanding is correct, I would present this as a set of functions $S_{a,j}(t)$. I'd also remove the $\forall$ sign, and replace $i$ with $a$ (or rename $A$ to $I$) for the sake of consistency. So I'd introduce this with:

For any $a\in A$ and $j\in J$, the {{$j$-th scrunkliness coefficient of $a$}} will be a function of time. We write this as $S_{a,j}(t)$.

(Replace the text {{in braces}} with the actual relevant quantity - it might be "efficiency of person $a$ at job $j$", or "capacity of location $a$ for item $j$", or any number of other things. I'm not familiar with the field.)

I mean tuple here, instead of ordered pair, sorry for being mistaken. I have modified the question and its description.
